# primefaces inputext onblur event not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello I have an inputText on blur event that will send a signal to the backing bean, this bean contains a Boolean variable that determines if another input text will be enabled or not ... but I can not make this work, this is my code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/Template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="someForm">
<p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" life="3000"/>
<p:panelGrid border="0" id="panel">
<p:row>
<p:column width="350">
Title
</p:column>
<p:column colspan="2">
<p:inputText id="someId" value="#{someBean.somePropertie}">
<p:ajax event="blur" update="anotherInput" listener="#{someBean.onEvent}" />
</p:inputText>
</p:column>
</p:row>
<p:row>
<p:column width="350">title 2</p:column>
<p:column colspan="2">
<p:inputText id="anotherInput" converter="toUpperCaseConverter" value="#{someBean.somePropertie2}" 
disabled="#{someBean.bDisabled}"
/>
</p:column>
</p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SomeBean implements Serializable{

private boolean bDisabled;

private String somePropertie;
private String somePropertie2;

public void onEvent(){

System.out.println("DO SOMETHING");

this.bDisabled = true;

}

... getters and setters of properties and boolean ....

}
```

this is the main tamplate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
<h:head>
<title>..:: XXXXX ::..</title>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/default.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-growl{
position:absolute;
top:20%;
left:50%;
z-index:9999;
}

.ui-widget,.ui-widget .ui-widget {
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body style="background-color: #E1E1E1;">
<div id="page">
<div id="divHeader" style="height: 70px;">
<ui:insert name="header" >
<ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
</div>
<div id="divMenu" style="height: 50px;">
<ui:insert name="menu">
<ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
</div>
<div id="divContent">
<ui:insert id="content" name="content" >
<ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
</div>
</div>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

the converter:

```
@FacesConverter("toUpperCaseConverter")
public class ToUpperCaseConverter implements Converter {
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
return (String) value;
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
return (value != null) ? value.toUpperCase() : null;
}

}
```

any idea ???

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete, since it does not provide all the elements to reproduce the bug. You haven't provided the page that calls your element, neither the converter, etc.

JSF's debugger best friend is firebug. Always check for javascript errors and enable the network tab to see each request response body, which may contain "silent" error messages.

I'll take my risk trying to guess your problem :-)

Here's your code, slightly changed to run in my primefaces 4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>You NEED a header</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:include src="index2.xhtml" />   
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <p:growl
            id="msg"
            showDetail="true"
            life="3000" />
        <p:panelGrid
            border="0"
            id="panel">
            <p:row>
                <p:column width="350">
Title
</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <p:inputText
                        id="someId"
                        value="#{someBean.somePropertie}">
                        <p:ajax
                            event="blur"
                            update="anotherInput"
                            listener="#{someBean.onEvent}" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column width="350">title 2</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <p:inputText
                        id="anotherInput"
                        value="#{someBean.somePropertie2}"
                        disabled="#{someBean.bDisabled}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

The managed bean is pretty much the same

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SomeBean implements Serializable {

    private boolean bDisabled;

    private String somePropertie;
    private String somePropertie2;

    public void onEvent() {

        System.out.println("DO SOMETHING");

        this.bDisabled = true;

    }

    public boolean isbDisabled() {
        return this.bDisabled;
    }

    public void setbDisabled(boolean bDisabled) {
        this.bDisabled = bDisabled;
    }

    public String getSomePropertie() {
        return this.somePropertie;
    }

    public void setSomePropertie(String somePropertie) {
        this.somePropertie = somePropertie;
    }

    public String getSomePropertie2() {
        return this.somePropertie2;
    }

    public void setSomePropertie2(String somePropertie2) {
        this.somePropertie2 = somePropertie2;
    }

}
```

I've noticed that if you don't omit the HEAD section from the caller page, it seems to render and work.

But if you forget the **HEAD** section (you must not, see [Primefaces FAQ](http://primefaces.org/faq.html) item #2), you'll render the page (quite) but you'll get some javascript errors and your page won't work. The HEAD section I am talking about is this

```
<h:head>
    <title>You NEED a header</title>
</h:head>
```

This is how it looks without the HEAD section.

[image]

With the HEAD section, it seems to work. Also notice the subtle primefaces look and feel.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, I updated the code in question, the header that I have in the main header tamplate is that you mean?

Comment: how your template looks like?

Comment: i posted in the original question :)